# How to set the driver memory in a Spring Boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-spark

I am trying to run Spark in local mode using Spring boot which will eventually be deployed as a Docker container.

What is the right way to set the driver memory?

The spark configuration page https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html says that for client mode it has to be before the JVM starts when running in embedded how can one pass these params?

The Spark configuration file that I am using.

```
@Configuration
public class SparkConfiguration {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SparkConfiguration.class);

    @Value("${config.spark.worker.threads}")
    private String workerThreads;

    @Value("${config.spark.driver.memory}")
    private String driveryMemory;

    @Value("${config.spark.sql.shuffle.partitions}")
    private String shuffleParitions;

    @Bean
    public SparkSession sparkSession() {
//        Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF);
//        Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF);

        SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
                .master(getWorkerThreadCount())
                .appName("API-Spark")

                /*  Spark UI Config */
                .config("spark.ui.enabled", true)
                .config("spark.ui.killEnabled", true)
                .config("spark.ui.retainedJobs", 100)
                .config("spark.ui.retainedStages", 100)
                .config("spark.ui.retainedTasks", 1000)
                /* Spark performance configs */
                .config("spark.driver.memory", driveryMemory)
                .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",shuffleParitions)
                .config("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled",true)
                .getOrCreate();

        Map<String, String> all = sparkSession.conf().getAll();

        LOGGER.info(" Spark runtime config "+all);

        LOGGER.info("Started Spark App ::: UI at : " + sparkSession.sparkContext().uiWebUrl().get());
        return sparkSession;
    }

    private String getWorkerThreadCount() {
        return "local[WORKER_THREAD_COUNT]".replace("WORKER_THREAD_COUNT", workerThreads);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have any error?

Comment: I do not have an error. But latency is high. 3 sec for every SQL query

Comment: I which environment is under 3 seconds? Maybe is the session is open in each connection. Is there a kind of connection pool?

Comment: No. There is just one Spark Session.
Using  sparkSession.read()
                .format("jdbc") to make the JDBC call

Comment: In all honesty, I think this looks quite fine. I would be more interested in the JDB query you do.

Comment: did you cache the dataset after the first read of the jdbc table? 
By default spark read from the source for every query that you execute over that dataset if you can't cache the dataset. By the way running spark on a local mode it's not a good stuff to do. The local mode must be used only for testing purpose

Comment: I cannot cache it. I form the query at runtime. I agree local mode is not the right approach. But I am trying to figure out what is the cause of the latency and how local mode works

Comment: The local mode execute your job on a single machine with the parallelism executed in a multi-threading way. So it's not a real distributed processing but it's a multithread processing. 
You can check how spark works for the query by analyzing the spark UI and the DAG provided on the relative ip:port that you setup for the docker container. 
By the way for each query spark read from db and execute the transformation. Each time load all data from the source again and again.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a [SparkContext](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext) in `SparkSession sparkSession()` explicitly for the `spark.driver.memory` configuration properties to take effect. In the current setup, it's simply too late.

You may want to use web UI's Environment tab to see whether this `spark.driver.memory` configuration property is set to the correct value.

Comment: I understand part of your answer but not all of it. I understand, and already knew, the "it's simply too late" part (it's my understanding that setting master to `local[x]` will use the current JVM as a driver and executor, making unavoidable that the current JVM's memory settings will be used). I also know you can connect to a cluster, and have your driver instanciated "there". But from what I read/understand in your answer, one could "create a Spark context (...) explicitely" that escapes the local JVM (and its memory) ? Do I understand that right ? Care to expand on how to do that ?

Comment: You do understand it right. Until a SparkContext is created (implicitly using SparkSession or explicitly) there's no driver or executors. That's the moment where you want to be in to assign the memory and others.

Answer (score 0):

What I did in the past was to have a dedicate script for each driver, that is utilising the `spark-submit` command to run the driver either in `local mode` or against an `existing cluster` (local or remote).

E.g. the script could do:

```
<spark-install-dir>/bin/spark-submit --class=gy.etiolo.BlaBlaDriver --driver-memory=12G --master=<url> path/to/driver/driver.jar <main-class-args>
```

To run in `local mode`: `url=local[*]` (* means use all cores)

To run against a remote cluster: `url=spark://<cluster-master-node-ip>:7077`

Regarding how to start your SparkSession, as you see I do not set the `master` url on the `SparkSession`, I just define it on the above script. This will give you the flexibility to have your docker commands as you fancy.

```
SparkSession session = SparkSession
                                 .builder()
                                 .appName("anExampleName")
                                 .getOrCreate()
```

Although I am fan of Spring Boot, I do not see any reason to use SpringBoot for a Spark driver, nothing important to gain. Actually, now that I think of it.. it may cause you issues, as spring jars have a Spring Boot specific file structure and not a regular one and it might cause you issues if you use Spark UDFs (you will not be able to submit them properly to the Spark classpath).

Comment: I have embedded Spark inside Spring boot. SparkSession is a Singelton bean. My current issue is that when I post concurrent request the performance is not good. I am doing a SparkSession.read().load() using JDBC.

Comment: You should update your question or create a new one, as you do not ask anything regarding execution speed or provide any querying code. It is very difficult to understand your question if you do not provide the part of your code that is slow.

Comment: I agree. I will do the same.